# How to restore file from rsnapshot backup with correct permissions

Tags: rsnapshot

I have installed a fresh version of Debian. I would like to restore some files in `home` with my backuped version as well as some under `etc`. The backup was created with rsnapshot.

The point which is not that clear to me is as which user should I run the restore command. Let me make an example. Assume I would like to restore my `rsnapshot`file within `/etc/cron.d/`. By default I see the following right permission in the fresh installed version:

```
station:~$ ls -l /etc/cron.d/rsnapshot 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 472 Mar 26  2016 /etc/cron.d/rsnapshot
```

In this case I need to run the rsync command as root or sudo, i.e. I was doing for testing:

```
@thinkstation:~$ rsync /media/3985DAA24356D774/rsnapshot/station/daily.0/etc/etc/cron.d/rsnapshot /etc/cron.d/rTest
```

But this leads to the following permissions:

```
station:~$ ls -l /etc/cron.d/rTest 
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 513 Sep 24 19:01 /etc/cron.d/rTest
```

and this doesn't match the system defaults one.

Another example, which is more frustrating. I was running rsync command as normal user (non root, non sudo). The files I've restored was a project which is version controlled via git. I did the restore because not all files were on github. After the restore I've seen a lot of difference because of the changed permission (which I don't understand as the files didn't involve any sudo rights and were transferred to my `home` directory). So I'm not sure if I did a mistake in the past while doing the backup or if I'm doing something wrong in restoring the files. In any case I would like to know how I can resolve that issue.

Comment: Please include the permission errors you got.

Comment: @FaheemMitha I've updated my post. I think I was not very clear at the beginning. I'm sorry for that. Let me know if there is still something missing. cheers

Comment: Hi. I haven't really taken the time to understand your issue, but consider other kinds of backup. I've been using Borg backup recently. It's a modern deduplicating backup. Check it out.

Answer (score 2):

You need to tell *rsync* you want to restore permissions. Judging from `man 1 rsync` I would propose the following options for restoring a single file:

```
-p, --perms                 preserve permissions
-t, --times                 preserve modification times
-o, --owner                 preserve owner (super-user only)
-g, --group                 preserve group
```

The `-a` often proposed to restore things from rsync based backups includes more options you don't need for a single file. So your command would look like follows:

```
rsync -ptog /media/3985DAA24356D774/rsnapshot/station/daily.0/etc/etc/cron.d/rsnapshot /etc/cron.d/rTest
```

Or with long options:

```
rsync --perms --times --owner --group /media/3985DAA24356D774/rsnapshot/station/daily.0/etc/etc/cron.d/rsnapshot /etc/cron.d/rTest
```

Because you specify `--owner` and `--group` this should work for both of your usecases.

If you want to restore a directory recursively, not only a single file, you might find this `-a` option useful, perhaps in combination with `-v`, which tells you what was copied:

```
-a, --archive               archive mode; equals -rlptgoD (no -H,-A,-X)
-v, --verbose               increase verbosity
```